# rigid body simulation

Tags: animation, rigidbody

I would like to create a container full of objects (bolts) tip the box up and pour and catch them into another container to view as an animation, is this possible and any tips would be helpful as fairly new to working with physics, thank you

Comment: Hi there, I'd recommend watching a couple of Youtube videos to get started with physics simulations, as they often proved every detail needed. Blender Guru should have a few and so should a couple of other people as it's quite a popular and fun thing to do in Blender. 1 tip I'd give straight off is to be wary of how big your simulation is, because if it's big it's highly likely that it'll crash your computer and if you haven't saved you'll have to start over again. Hope you enjoy!

Comment: yes i love blender gur!, ive filled the box successfully, im just unsure how i can then move the box with the objects in situ and then gradually tip the objects out of the box again? as they currently start as a mass of objects floating in space, it may mean several separate animations and a bit of AE to construct the sequence im after

Comment: Try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnvCC4oyvkY it should explain how to animate and move your boxes using keyframes

Comment: thanks, im fairly confident with key frame animation, its combining it with the physics simulation thats a bit painful, ill keep researching :)

Comment: i have managed to solve this by extending the duration between keyframes on the timeline, and amending the gravity settings, this meant i could move the box with the contents and everything stay in situ as opposed to flying around like someone was flinging the products out of the box in a rage!

Comment: Great! I hope you'll show us when it's done!